# Java - Create multiple HashMaps and fill them using a for loop - is there a better way?

Tags: java, loops, dynamic, hashmap

To be clear from the start, I have already "solved" this problem (and will post my code at the end). However, my solution seems very hacky and contains a large amount of repetitive code.

My questions are:

- Is there a better/proper way to do this?
- Should I use something other than a HashMap?
- Should I use something other than a for loop?

What I am trying to do:

I need to create between 16 and 20 items (the number varies, but I don't think that matters so I'll just say 20 from now on) and each item has 25 attributes (such as "name", "power", level", etc). Each of the 20 items has the same attributes but with different (random) values.

It seems like a `HashMap` is the obvious way to do this, but I'm open to alternative suggestions. I chose to go with a nested `HashMap`, so I have the outerMap which contains 20 keys and the value of each key is the `HashMap` for 1 item and its 25 attributes. So, to be more precise: I need to create 20 `HashMaps` with unique names and each of them with the same 25 keys but with different (random) values.

Again, it seems like a for loop is the obvious way to do this. And, if Java allowed for creating names dynamically (like Item+i for Item1), this would be a simple task. But that's not possible. There are specifically 2 problems I am running in to while trying to do this in a loop.

1. Naming the 20 `HashMaps`. If I create the `HashMaps` inside a loop there is no way to assign each of them a unique name (such as Item1, Item2, Item3, etc).
2. When I try to use "put" to store the attribute keys and values I need the current `HashMap` name. Basically the same as problem 1, but at a different point in the code.

This is the solution I came up with. The comments in the code should make it clear why I'm doing it this way. Thoughts?

```
//create outerMap to hold the HashMap for each item
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> itemMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); 

    //create all possible innerMaps
    //manually because you can't name them dynamically in the for loop (example Item+i)
    //amount of items unknown, but the range is 16-20
    //if less than 20 the remaining HashMaps will simply remain unused
    Map<String, Object> Item1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> Item2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> Item3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> Item4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Map<String, Object> Item5 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    ...through Item20

    //for loop that creates and manipulates each of the 25 attributes for each of the 16-20 items
    //starting at i = 1 for aesthetic naming purposes
    for (i = 1; i < (NumberOfItems + 1); i++)
        {
            ...create and manipulate attribute1
            ...create and manipulate attribute2
            ...create and manipulate attribute3
            ...create and manipulate attribute4
            ...create and manipulate attribute5
            ...through attribute25

            //you can't call HashMap names dynamically (example Item+i.put(Key, Value)
            //so run them through if statements to match i to the correct HashMap
            if (i == 1)
            {
                itemMap.put("Item1", Item1);
                Item1.put("attribute1", value);
                Item1.put("attribute2", value);
                Item1.put("attribute3", value);
                ...through attribute25

            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                itemMap.put("Item2", Item2);
                Item2.put("attribute1", value);
                Item2.put("attribute2", value);
                Item2.put("attribute3", value);
                ...through attribute25
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                itemMap.put("Item3", Item3);
                Item3.put("attribute1", value);
                Item3.put("attribute2", value);
                Item3.put("attribute3", value);
                ...through attribute25
            }
            ...through i == 20  
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a class to store the attributes instead of HashMap? Like `class Hero { String name; int powerlvl; //etc... }`

Comment: create a pojo mapping to all your attributes and instantiate using parameterized constructor.... and then finally put it into map under different dynamic keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 1 HashMap  with the attributes defined as instance variables of a class (who's objects are the values of the HashMap.

**ValueObject** - Class the holds your attributes.

```
class ValueObject {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    ...
    ...
    private String attr25;

    public void setAttr1(String a1){
        attr1 = a1;
    }

    public String getAttr1(){
        return attr1;
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Creating the map** - The number of elements added are dynamic.

```
Map<String, ValueObject> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();


for (i = 1; i < (NumberOfItems + 1); i++)
{
    ValueObject vo = new ValueObject();
    vo.setAttr1("a1");
    vo.setAttr2("a2");
    vo.setAttr3("a3");
    ...
    ...
    vo.setAttr25("a25");

    map1.put("item"+i,vo);
}
```

Comment: In retrospect using a Class to hold the attributes and then just create Objects from the Class is blindingly obvious. :( The problem was I started from the beginning and worked forward instead of looking at what I would need in the end and working backward. So using a HashMap to create 1 item with attributes was the obvious choice but when I went to needing 20 items I stuck with the idea of a HashMap and for some reason it didn't occur to me to just use a Class. Marking this as the accepted answer because it contains (to me) the clearest way to implement the Class idea to do what I need. Ty!

Comment: I thought I might elaborate on my previous comment as it may help other people when they get stuck at some point with any type of coding. 

Just because the you found the best solution to do something small in scope does not mean the same solution, or a variation of that solution, is the best way to go when you move to a larger scope. To help avoid falling into this trap, imagine what the end result of your project will look like and work backwards from there to find simpler ways of getting that result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set them in a loop.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
String[] names = {"item1", "item2"};

for (String name : names) {
   Map<String, Object> itemMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   map.put(name, itemMap);
   // Add stuff to itemMap
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a good solution (that never occurred to me) for the way I was trying to solve the problem. However, this is a moot point now because a Class is a much better approach to the overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `Map`, I would like to suggest creating a class for holding the attributes of each item, because seems like the items all have the same attributes (same name, different value of course). This will give you a lot of benefits, such as better code clarity, better performance.

Anyway, say you have defined this class `Item`, the next thing is to create 20 or so items and put them in a `Map` so that you can later reference them with the key.

```
Map<String, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfItems; i++) {
    // item is a local variable, whose scope is restricted
    // to the loop body. We can reuse this name because each
    // time we create a new item.
    // The same variable but different object.
    Item item = new Item();
    // Code to intialize item's attributes

    // Populate the item map, here it's perfectly ok to dynamically create keys.
    itemMap.put("Item"+(i+1), item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is indeed the obvious and best route to go (as I stated on a different answer). Jerin Joseph's code example seemed more clear to me, so I chose his as the accepted answer, but both of you supplied the key to solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

While Jerin Joseph and Luke Lee answered this problem correctly, I can think of a different design here.

Look at this code; you are trying to preserve the insert order with LinkedHashmap (instead of just hashmap). And the key is "item"+i, which is a hard-coded value+index. At this point, I would use Arraylist instead of LinkedHashMap. Because we will get the same result with ArrayList ie,

1. preserve the order
2. O(1) retrieval once you have the key (index)

> ```
> Map<String, ValueObject> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
>
>
> for (i = 1; i < (NumberOfItems + 1); i++)
> {
>     ValueObject vo = new ValueObject();
>     vo.setAttr1("a1");
>     vo.setAttr2("a2");
>     vo.setAttr3("a3");
>     ...
>     ...
>     vo.setAttr25("a25");
>
>     map1.put("item"+i,vo);
> }
> ```

I would rather change it as

```
    List<ValueObject> list1 = new ArrayList<ValueObject>();


    for (i = 0; i < NumberOfItems; i++)
    {
        ValueObject vo = new ValueObject();
        vo.setAttr1("a1");
        vo.setAttr2("a2");
        vo.setAttr3("a3");
...
...
        vo.setAttr25("a25");

        list1.add(vo);
    }
```